# Client doclinks disappearing when saved in web

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

and thanks for reading - I feel like I am at my wit's end here...

I am converting a lotus notes client database to domino (not XPages).  Many of the documents in the notes client database have multiple doclinks in them.  I have started to web-enable this database and when I open one of these documents in the web interface, the doclinks do appear in the same rich text fields on the web interface (good), but if the document is edited and saved in the web, the links disappear (not good).  I am using TinyMCE as my rich text editor in the web.

How do I maintain these doclinks in the web version of this database so that when docs are edited and saved the doclinks don't disappear?  I took away TinyMCE with an idea that might be the problem, but it still goes on.

I looked at the document properties, and the only thing I can find that holds any information about the doclinks is in the $Links field.  Do I have to go in, extract that information, and then massage it into an HTML link to put back into that same rich text field?

This is not an "`<NDL>` to URL" problem, I have seen other posts that address that issue.  I'm not even at the NDL stage in this example.

Any suggestions would be a great help - thanks again for reading.

Comment: Honestly, there's only one easy solution, and its a paid third-party tool: [AppsFidelity Edit](http://www.geniisoft.com/showcase.nsf/CoexEdit) from Genii Software. Other than that, you're on the right track - although it may be somewhat easier to use DXL manipulation than native back-end methods.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Is this a common problem?  I feel like I have scoured the internet and haven't found much at all.  Surely other people have encountered this....?

Comment: If you mean "is it widely understood that rich text field editing on the web is only minimally compatible with the Notes client?" then yes. It's one of the main reasons the Rich Text Lite field type exists - keeping the chocolate and the peanut butter separate makes it much easier to create cross-client applications, but at a cost in UX. In R5, the "easy" solution was separate applications with code to stitch things together and synchronize (the two apps could live in the same NSF, but would be separate nonetheless).